# Element not found: Trying to verify a disabled button

Tags: testing, xpath, automation, automated-tests, katalon-studio

Trying to verify this button if it is disable on the page :

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" xpath="1">
  <div class="pull-right" style="">
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="registrationForm.$invalid|| vm.payload.ConfirmPassword!=  vm.payload.Password|| vm.payload.ConfirmEmail!= vm.payload.Email|| vm.isAgreed== false|| vm.payload.GRecaptchaResponse== ''" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" value="Register and Continue" disabled="disabled" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

But every time I run it, it says Element not found:(using katalon) Tried adding delay()/ waitForElement but got the same error.

This is the xpath I am using :
`//div[@class='btn-group pull-right']`

---

```
WebUI.delay(10)

WebUI.verifyElementNotClickable(findTestObject('H3. Sign Up/H3.5 Providing correct details (Profile and Contact page) without checking Terms and Conditions and Captcha/Page_Demo Bookie (BETA)/Register And Continue Button'))
```

---

Below is the full error log

> 03-01-2019 01:39:17 PM Test Cases/H3. Sign Up/H3.5 Providing correct details (Profile and Contact page) without checking Terms and Conditions and Captcha
>
> Elapsed time: 55.445s
>
> Test Cases/H3. Sign Up/H3.5 Providing correct details (Profile and
> Contact page) without checking Terms and Conditions and Captcha
> FAILED. Reason: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException:
> Unable to verify object 'Object Repository/H3. Sign Up/H3.5 Providing
> correct details (Profile and Contact page) without checking Terms and
> Conditions and Captcha/Page_Demo Bookie (BETA)/RegisterButton' to be
> NOT clickable (Root cause:
> com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Web element with
> id: 'Object Repository/H3. Sign Up/H3.5 Providing correct details
> (Profile and Contact page) without checking Terms and Conditions and
> Captcha/Page_Demo Bookie (BETA)/RegisterButton' located by 'By.xpath:
> //*[@//div[@class='btn-group pull-right']//input =
> '//div[@class="btn-group pull-right"]//input']' not found)    at
> com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy:36)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:65)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:27)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.VerifyElementNotClickableKeyword.verifyElementNotClickable(VerifyElementNotClickableKeyword.groovy:96)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.VerifyElementNotClickableKeyword.execute(VerifyElementNotClickableKeyword.groovy:67)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:53)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.verifyElementNotClickable(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:591)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$verifyElementNotClickable$4.call(Unknown
> Source)   at H3.5 Providing correct details (Profile and Contact page)
> without checking Terms and Conditions and Captcha.run(H3.5 Providing
> correct details (Profile and Contact page) without checking Terms and
> Conditions and Captcha:86)    at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)     at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:321)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:291)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:283)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:222)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:106)
> at
> com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:97)
> at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
> Source)   at
> TempTestCase1551411555685.run(TempTestCase1551411555685.groovy:22)

Can anyone help me or share any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Please, add the full error log.

Comment: already updated the full error log please check

Comment: Your xpath looks strange. Why are you repeating the path two times? Maybe try with css selector instead: `"div.btn-group.pull-right input"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should target the `input` element with the following xpath:

```
//div[@class='btn-group pull-right']//input
```

or with css selector:

```
div.btn-group.pull-right input
```

Comment: Hi, tried your suggestion but still got the same error